# MongoDB селектор $all

Tags: mongodb

Добрый день! Не могу разобраться с этим селектором. Пишу такие запросы, в консоле:

```
db.test.find({"seazon":{$all:["1"]}})
db.test.find({"seazon":{$all:["2"]}})
db.test.find({"seazon":{$all:["3"]}})
```

все работает. Но вот такой запрос, что ниже, не работает (ничего не возвращает, никаких ошибок не выдает)

```
db.test.find({"seazon":{$all:["1","2","3"]}})
```

Почему? Версия MongoDB 2.6.0
Пример документа:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a200489ba29030fc05f9df1"),
        "img" : [
                "20_0.jpg",
                "20_1.jpg",
                "20_2.jpg",
                "20_3.jpg"
        ],
        "pact" : "2344",
        "name" : "укчфа",
        "price" : "443",
        "quality" : "new",
        "category" : "boy",
        "subCategory" : "blouse",
        "seazon" : "3",
        "path" : "fotoTest\\boy\\blouse",
        "article" : 20
}
```

Comment: что значит не работает? что возвращает?покажите пример документа.

Comment: @C.Raf.T, Не работает, имеется, в виду - ничего не возвращает. Никаких ошибок не выдает.(исправил в вопросе) Курсор(в консоле) переходит на новую строчку и Mongo ждет новой команды. Пример документа добавил в вопрос

Comment: $all экивалентин $and и данный документ запрос $all:["1","2", "3"] не найдет. ваш запрос выглядит так : "найди мне все документы, где в поле seazon есть 1 и 2 и 3"..

Comment: @C.Raf.T, Спасибо! Понятно. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: нет, удачи....)